# How to use Glade XML file to generate c++ code for GTK?

Tags: c++, glade

I know how to use Glade generated XML file (`*.glade`) and to load it in c++ code.
But for educational purpose I need to see the c++ source code alternative to the XML file. I just want to see the same GUI (made on Glade with output in XML format), but in c++ source code with the GTK+ library classes explicitly defined.

Meanwhile I've found [this tool](https://www.freebasic-portal.de/downloads/ressourcencompiler/gladetobac-190.html) and hopefully it is compatible with the latest Glade XML code.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Are you looking for something like this: https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-text-entry.html.en

Comment: @MartinSand Glade generates `*.glade` file, which is in XML code. I want to take this file and to generate `*.cpp` file that represents the GUI of the Glade XML file.

Comment: Ah, ok. I am not aware about a tool to do this. I once did it manually. Is there any reason why you want to do this?

Comment: @MartinSand Mainly because of educational purpose. Also because I have some GTK+ projects that do not use Glade and I can use Glade here just for easy reference instead of writing the GTK+ code for every widget.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I do it is to make a c file with [`glib-compile-resource`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/glib-compile-resources.html) and add it as a resource. Note glib-compile-resource only compiles resources listed /defined in a defined xml file. You have to create resources.xml. All you do is regenerate the c file and add it to your program. with gcc resource.c youprogram.cpp etc. In your code use builder->add_from_resouce. See [Glade and Builder](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/chapter-builder.html). That way you dont have to worry about generating cpp files.

Comment: see glib-compile-resource documentation you probably are trying to compile a glade file directly with glib-compile-resource dont do that

Answer (score 0):

While it is not what you have asked for, maybe [GtkInspector](http://GtkInspector) will help. It allows to inspect native Gtk at runtime and manipulate it, you can gain insights (*"What was actually applied to Gtk?"*) and modify internals on the fly - without recompiling.

It can be compared to *Web Inspector* from WebKit.